# error: missing opencv_features2d (STATIC_LIBRARIES android-arm)"

Tags: opencv, android-ndk, android-source, android.mk

I've created an application to read QR code using OpenCv.
When I try to build it using NDK, everything works well

```
NDK=/opt/android-ndk-r23c
export TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64
export TARGET=aarch64-linux-android
export API=21
export AR=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/llvm-ar
export CC=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/$TARGET$API-clang
export AS=$CC
export CXX=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/$TARGET$API-clang++
export LD=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/ld
export RANLIB=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/llvm-ranlib
export STRIP=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/llvm-strip
$NDK/ndk-build
```

But when I've tried to build it as a system application as part of the AOSP build I've got an error:

```
read_qr/jni/../../OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk: error: "read_qr (EXECUTABLES android-arm) missing opencv_features2d (STATIC_LIBRARIES android-arm)"
You can set ALLOW_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES=true in your environment if this is intentional, but that may defer real problems until later in the build.

read_qr/jni/../../OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk: error: "read_qr (EXECUTABLES android-arm) missing opencv_dnn (STATIC_LIBRARIES android-arm)"
You can set ALLOW_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES=true in your environment if this is intentional, but that may defer real problems until later in the build.

build/make/core/main.mk:1118: error: exiting from previous errors.
22:44:58 ckati failed with: exit status 1
```

And I have no idea what can be the problem.
This is my Android.mk and Application.mk files:

**Android.mk**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

# Location of SDK on my drive
OPENCVROOT := ${LOCAL_PATH}/../../OpenCV-android-sdk
OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES := off
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES := on
OPENCV_LIB_TYPE := STATIC
TARGET_ARCH_ABI := armeabi-v7a

include ${OPENCVROOT}/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

# Load your local .cpp and .h files here.
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := readQr.cpp

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lm -llog -ldl -lz
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -fexceptions -frtti -std=c++17
LOCAL_LDFLAGS += -ljnigraphics

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += ${OPENCVROOT}/sdk/native/jni/include \
  ${OPENCVROOT}/sdk/native/jni/include/opencv2

LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES += ${OPENCVROOT}/sdk/native/jni/include \
  ${OPENCVROOT}/sdk/native/jni/include/opencv2

LOCAL_MODULE := read_qr

include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)

APP_PLATFORM := android-21
```

**Application.mk**

```
APP_STL := c++_static
APP_CPPFLAGS += -fexceptions -frtti -std=c++11 -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS

APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
APP_PLATFORM := android-21
```

Can someone help me to understand what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved by changing the Android.mk
from:

```
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

to

```
include $(BUILD_STATIC_EXECUTABLE)
```